# Split log file by date

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a log file with this log format:

```
###<Aug 8, 2016 11:59:05 PM>
different text
...
different text
###<Aug 15, 2016 9:10:55 AM>
different text
...
...
...
different text
###<Aug 22, 2016 10:02:17 PM>
different text
...
...
...
...
different text
###<Sep 1, 2016 1:00:01 AM>
different text
###<Sep 7, 2016 3:00:01 PM>
different text
...
...
different text
```

How do I split this log file by date to files YYYY_MM_DD.log?

Comment: maybe [logrotate](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html) helps you, it is fairly easy to use.

Comment: Use the `axe` command.

Answer (score 7):

A `perl` solution, taking advantage of GNU `date` to convert the dates:

```
perl -ne 'if(/^###<(.*)>/){
            chomp($d=`date -d \"$1\" +%Y_%m_%d`);
            $name="$d.log"
          } 
          open(my $fh,">>","$name"); 
          print $fh $_;' file.log
```

#### Explanation

- `-ne` : read the input file line by line (saving each line as the special variable `$_`) and apply the script given by `-e` to each line.
- `if(/^###<(.*)>/)` : if the line starts with `###<`, capture everything between the `<>` as `$1` (that's what the parentheses do).
- `chomp($d=`date -d \"$1\" +%Y_%m_%d`);` : the `date` command reformats the date. For example:

  ```
  $ date -d "Sep 1, 2016 1:00:01 AM" +%Y_%m_%d
  2016_09_01
  ```

  The `chomp` removes the final newline from the result of `date` so we can use it later.
- `$name="$d.log"` : we save the result of the `date` command plus `.log` as the variable `$name`.
- `open(my $fh,">>","$name");` : open the file `$name` as the file handle `$fh`. Don't worry if you don't know what a file handle is, this just means that `print $fh "foo"` will print `foo` into `$name`.
- `print $fh $_;` : print the current line into the file that the file handle `$fh` points to. So, print the line into whatever is currently saved as `$name`.

Answer (score 6):

One approach for solving this could be to use awk. For example, this command:

```
awk -F'[ <,]+' '/^###/{close(f);f=$4"_"$2"_"$3".log"}{print >> f}END{close(f)}' file
```

should split the file into the files, using the date fields as filenames

Comment: Nice! Note that this will create files called `2016_Sep_1.log` instead of `2016_09_01` which is what I think the OP asked for.

Comment: @terdon: That is correct. I left it like this for simplicity, but the answer could be adapted to use the `date` command like in the other two answers.

Answer (score 6):

With `awk`:

```
awk '/^#+<[^>]+>$/ {if (lines) print lines >file; \
     dt=gensub("^#+<([^>]+)>$", "\\1", $0)
     dt_cmd="date -d \""dt"\" +%Y_%m_%d.log" \
     dt_cmd | getline file; lines=$0; next}; \
     {lines=lines ORS $0} END {print lines >file}' file.log
```

Readable form:

```
awk '
      /^#+<[^>]+>$/ {
                    if (lines) 
                        print lines >file
                    dt=gensub("^#+<([^>]+)>$", "\\1", $0)
                    dt_cmd="date -d \""dt"\" +%Y_%m_%d.log"
                    dt_cmd | getline file; lines=$0
                    next
                    }
      {
      lines=lines ORS $0
      } 
      END {
          print lines >file
          }' file.log
```

- `/^#+<[^>]+>$/` matches the lines containing dates, the chunk surrounded by `{}` will only be run if the condition matches. If matches, we are getting the date in desired format by using external `date` command and saving the output in variable `file`, and saving the content of variable `lines` so far as file `file` (from previous chunk), and then instantiate the variable `lines` again with the line
- For all other lines, we concatenating the lines as variable `lines`
- The last chunk is saved by putting in the `END` block